# Get number of elements inside of an element in xml with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this xml file:

```
<row>
    <question name="faq"></question>
    <answer name="faq"></answer>
    <question_down name="faq"></question_down>
    <answer_down name="faq"></answer_down>
    <question_down name="faq"></question_down>
    <answer_down name="faq"></answer_down>
    <question_down name="faq"></question_down>
    <answer_down name="faq"></answer_down>
</row>
```

I want to know how many `<question_down>` elements I have inside `<row>`,
how can I do this using jQuery or pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's find function to grab an array of all elements matching the selector passed to it, within the current selection. So by selecting a 'row' element and then 'find'ing all the 'question_down' elements within it, you'll get an array of all the question_down elements, which you can count by using the length function of javascript.

Like this:-

```
  num_question_downs = $("row").find("question_down").length;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10811080)

Comment: hi i dont get the answer... i have many "row" how do i get the number of "gestion_down" inside specific row?

Comment: This is using jQuery to count the question_down tags inside of a row element. If you have several rows then you'll need to locate the row first (maybe using $("row").eq(x).find("question_down").length where x is the row index that you're interested in? - you're example xml only showed a single row!

Comment: @Luca Detomi - I don't understand what I haven't answered here? I tested it locally and it works for me on the XML provided. Sure it's not a complete piece of code, but it should give the OP enough information to solve his problem?

Comment: @DarrenCrabb - It's not a problem of "correctness", simply in SO is suggested to explain answers giving users as many detail as possible to understand "why" this is the right answer. I suggest you to edit your answer to better explain that and so make it the better one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method here to find specific elements within another element. Here you want to find `<question_down>` inside `<row>`

```js
question_down_num = $("row")    //any <row> element
  .find("question_down")        //find  any element called <question_down> in that <row>
  .length;                      //find the length of the <question_down> array,
                                   //i.e. how many <question_down> elements exist in <row>
document.write(question_down_num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<row>
  <question name="faq">  </question>
  <answer name="faq"></answer>
  <question_down name="faq"></question_down>
  <answer_down name="faq"></answer_down>
  <question_down name="faq"></question_down>
  <answer_down name="faq"></answer_down>
  <question_down name="faq"></question_down>
  <answer_down name="faq"></answer_down>
</row>
```